# Monero wallet RPC does not use HTTPS?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

The examples on https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html for using the monero wallet rpc has all the examples running over http not https and I can't seem to get them to work over https.

Is this not supposed to use https?

Answer (score 2):

Both the RPC wallet and daemon support SSL.

```
$ monero-wallet-rpc --help | grep ssl -A 3
  --daemon-ssl arg (=autodetect)        Enable SSL on daemon RPC connections: 
                                        enabled|disabled|autodetect
  --daemon-ssl-private-key arg          Path to a PEM format private key
  --daemon-ssl-certificate arg          Path to a PEM format certificate
  --daemon-ssl-ca-certificates arg      Path to file containing concatenated 
                                        PEM format certificate(s) to replace 
                                        system CA(s).
  --daemon-ssl-allowed-fingerprints arg List of valid fingerprints of allowed 
                                        RPC servers
  --daemon-ssl-allow-any-cert           Allow any SSL certificate from the 
                                        daemon
  --daemon-ssl-allow-chained            Allow user (via --daemon-ssl-ca-certifi
                                        cates) chain certificates
  --rpc-ssl arg (=autodetect)           Enable SSL on RPC connections: 
                                        enabled|disabled|autodetect
  --rpc-ssl-private-key arg             Path to a PEM format private key
  --rpc-ssl-certificate arg             Path to a PEM format certificate
  --rpc-ssl-ca-certificates arg         Path to file containing concatenated 
                                        PEM format certificate(s) to replace 
                                        system CA(s).
  --rpc-ssl-allowed-fingerprints arg    List of certificate fingerprints to 
                                        allow
  --rpc-ssl-allow-chained               Allow user (via --rpc-ssl-certificates)
                                        chain certificates

$ monerod --help | grep ssl -A 3
  --rpc-ssl arg (=autodetect)           Enable SSL on RPC connections: 
                                        enabled|disabled|autodetect
  --rpc-ssl-private-key arg             Path to a PEM format private key
  --rpc-ssl-certificate arg             Path to a PEM format certificate
  --rpc-ssl-ca-certificates arg         Path to file containing concatenated 
                                        PEM format certificate(s) to replace 
                                        system CA(s).
  --rpc-ssl-allowed-fingerprints arg    List of certificate fingerprints to 
                                        allow
  --rpc-ssl-allow-chained               Allow user (via --rpc-ssl-certificates)
                                        chain certificates
  --rpc-ssl-allow-any-cert              Allow any peer certificate
```

If none of the options are specified, the default (`--rpc-ssl arg (=autodetect)`) applies, which causes the wallet/daemon to present a self-signed certificate to any client that attempts an SSL connection - it's then up to your client to either allow or reject this self-signed certificate. If you already have a CA signed cert, or any other you'd like to use, then start your wallet/daemon with the relevant options.